# Unable to bind phpseclib to specific source IP

Tags: ssh, network-programming, scp, phpseclib

It looks like the SSH / SCP code for phpseclib does not support binding to a source IP.  Unfortunately, this breaks our use case.

Is there a way to add this support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpseclib uses fsockopen to do SSH, which doesn't support binding. You could probably rewrite it to do [socket_create](http://php.net/socket-create) / [socket_bind](http://php.net/socket-bind). I guess I could do it if you paypal me some money!